# how to get cardinality in elasticsearch url php

Tags: php, curl, elasticsearch, cardinality

I am getting the cardinality count using `Curl` it was working fine. I need to get the same result in URL passing.

here is my curl query

```
$json = '{
    "query": {
        "multi_match": {
            "query":       "Associate",  
            "fields":      ["jt_tax"]
        } 
    },
    "aggs" : {
    "lawfirmcount" : {
        "cardinality" : {
            "field" : "pd_lawfirmID",
            "precision_threshold": 100
    }
   }
  }
}';

$params['index'] = 'jdbc';
$params['type']  = 'jdbc';
$params['body'] = $json;
$results = $client->search($params);
```

When i use the above query i received results as below

```
"aggregations": {
        "lawfirmcount": {
            "value": 226
        }
    }
```

This was correct result. I need to pass the same in below URL.

```
http://localhost:9200/jdbc/_search
```

Please help me.

Thanks in Advance